# Running Mysql on multiple core

Tags: mysql, multithreading, multicore

I'm running multiple select query on a single Innodb table, however it only uses 1 core when there are 7. I have a separate connection for each select query. When I run

```
show global status
```

The number of Threads_running is always correct. but the run time increases proportionally as the number of thread increases and the cpu usage stays the same. My thread concurrency is set at 18.
Is there any possible explanation for this 
Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-than-one-core) might be relevant...